# Receiving error "Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1101" while setting SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, speech

I am receiving the next error: `Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1101` if I'm setting the `SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true`.

In order to test it you can download the Apple Scrumdinger project from here:

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/transcribing-speech-to-text

The only thing that needs to be updated is in SpeechRecognizer.swift, change the prepareEngine function to look like this:

```
private static func prepareEngine() throws -> (AVAudioEngine, SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest) {
    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    
    let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    request.shouldReportPartialResults = true
    request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
    
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .measurement, options: .duckOthers)
    try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    
    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
        request.append(buffer)
    }
    audioEngine.prepare()
    try audioEngine.start()
    
    return (audioEngine, request)
}
```

The only thing that changed was that I added the line: `request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true`

Of course you can go further and test `SFSpeechRecognizer` in the init to see if it `supportsOnDeviceRecognition`, but for me returns true.

I am testing on a physical device: iPhone X with iOS 16.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

The error Code=1101 has to do with **incorrect/incomplete setup off offline dictation** on your device.

If you set `request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true` the recognition process uses Apple’s dictation service.

The dictation service only works offline if

1. you have the keyboard installed for the same language + region you want the dictation / speech recognition for
2. you have `Enable Dictation` toggled `On` and
3. the `Dictation Language` for the lang + region you want has been downloaded by the system.

**If the above conditions are not met, you will see the 1101 error.**

Example:

If you want offline dictation for `„de-DE“` (german language for region Germany) you need to have such a keyboard installed.
In the device's `Setting / General / Keyboard / Keyboards` … be sure to have the one keyboard installed for your lang + region speech recognition (in our example „German (Germany)“).
Further down in `General / Keyboard` turn on `Enable Dictation`.
If Dictation is enabled, you see a further entry below called `Dictation Languages`. Open it to make sure the dictation languages are downloaded (you see a note about the status there).

Once the dictation language(s) are downloaded, speech recognition with `request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true` should work for that language/region.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work.  I am using iOS 16.3.1 using iPhone 11 hardware.

Since you are using a version close to 16 (16.0.2) that notoriously is a version that tends to be buggy (since iOS 16 would have a product shipping deadline associated with it).

However, the app does not work all that well (my transcription experience is poor).

Studying the operating system and app behave via the Console app reveals a collaboration at the system level.

Say the app is Process ID 6984, then another process is launched, 6985, which is the local listener.  I have:

```
info    14:10:48.846966+0000    localspeechrecognition  -[LSRConnection initializeWithSandboxExtensions:]_block_invoke Successfully consumed sandbox extensions
```

Local speech recognition is the purpose of your desired setting and this process provides such a service.  I notice that it needs some sandbox entitlement to proceed.

I think upgrading your iPhone to the latest iOS version may be the simplest solution.  I would be interested in what error you get from the Console app logging of the iPhone operating system since this will be the upstream reason for your API error.  I suspect you won't see the localspeechrecognition service running, but you may be seeing an informative error instead.

If upgrading your phone does not help, please share any diagnostics so we can learn about the problem further.